# Woman are more than just garmets to wear

Tags: hadith, women, authenticity, reference-request

It is narrated on the account of Umar ibn Al-Khattab:

> “The women are not a garment you wear and undress however you like. They are honored and have their rights.”

What is the authenticity of this narration? I cannot find it anywhere for the life of me. Would appreciate a solid source to help grade this.